# Python recognizes the function count as a name

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am viewing the [Python tutorials from the Pascal institute](http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/python/ch01.html#sect_first_session) [BDFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum) says are the best to start and i have a very basic question

While in the [tutorial](http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/python/ch01.html#sect_first_session) says:

```
How many of each base does this sequence contains?

>>> count(seq, 'a')
35
>>> count(seq, 'c')
21
>>> count(seq, 'g')
44
>>> count(seq, 't')
12
```

When i try to do is it does not work

```
>>> count(seq, 'a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#140>", line 1, in <module>
    count(seq, 'a')
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

Why this is happening?

> > I' ve searched Stack resoures BTW and I didn't find anything.

COMMENT

Take a look at the start of the section 1.1.3. You have to type first from string import *

```
>>> from string import*
>>> nb_a = count(seq, 'a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#73>", line 1, in <module>
    nb_a = count(seq, 'a')
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
>>> from string import *
>>> nb_a = count(seq, 'a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#75>", line 1, in <module>
    nb_a = count(seq, 'a')
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

I did.

ANSWER

```
>>> from string import *
>>> from string import count
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#93>", line 1, in <module>
    from string import count
ImportError: cannot import name count
>>> from string import count
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#94>", line 1, in <module>
    from string import count
ImportError: cannot import name count
```

I did. Didn' t work.

Comment: Take a look at the start of the section 1.1.3. You have to type first `from string import *`.

Comment: I did but.... nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answers are correct, current Python releases propose another way to call `count`, as it is usable for `str` but also any type of `sequence`, as [advised inside the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

```
>>> seq.count('a')
35
```

As `seq` is as string *object*, it also have the `count` method.

Comment: So it is permanently changed! And it is stated this way. I have the Python 3.3.5

Comment: @Codo: You could and should have used this syntax in Python 2 too. [string.count](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) is listed as a deprecated function in Python 2.

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial you linked to is very old:

```
Python 2.4.2 (#1, Dec 20 2005, 16:25:40)
```

You're probably using a more modern Python (>= 3) in which case there are no longer string functions like `count` in the `string` module.  We used to have

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:39:55) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from string import count
>>> count("abcc", "c")
2
```

but today:

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:53:38) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from string import count
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name count
>>> import string
>>> dir(string)
['ChainMap', 'Formatter', 'Template', '_TemplateMetaclass', '__builtins__',
 '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__initializing__', '__loader__', '__name__',
 '__package__', '_re', '_string', 'ascii_letters', 'ascii_lowercase',
 'ascii_uppercase', 'capwords', 'digits', 'hexdigits', 'octdigits', 'printable', 
 'punctuation', 'whitespace']
```

These days we use the string *methods* instead, the ones that live in `str` itself:

```
>>> 'abcc'.count('c')
2
```

or even

```
>>> str.count('abcc','c')
2
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to debug this issue oneself by using `dir` on a module.

Comment: Yes i am using 3.3.5!

Answer (score 0):

This method`count()` is defined in `string` package. For using this method in your code, you need to import the definition.
Adding the following import statement before using the method will solve your problem

`from string import count`

```
>>> seq='acdaacc'
>>> count(seq,'a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
>>> from string import count
>>> count(seq,'a')
3
```

Comment: It says `cannot import name count`

Comment: @Codo which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`count` is a method in the string module, meaning that at the top of your file (before you use the function) you need to "import" it so that your interpreter knows what you're talking about.  Add the line `from string import count` as the first line of your file and it should work.

Comment: It says `cannot import name count`

Comment: You can't import it twice, which your code is doing.  You're also using a very old (and poorly written) tutorial.  If you're using Python 3, you should have a tutorial for that version.